# Rails Copying attributes from User object to new object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

In the User model I have an archive! method that is called when a User is destroyed. This action creates a new ArchivedUser in separate table.

The ArchivedUser is successfully created, but the way I am manually setting each value is pretty dirty; if a new column is added to the User table it must be added here as well.

I tried to `select` and `slice` the attributes, but got `undefined local variable or method`user'`

```
ArchivedUser.create(user.attributes.select{ |key, _| ArchivedUser.attribute_names.include? key })

ArchivedUser.create(user.attributes.slice(ArchivedUser.attribute_names))
```

How can I iterate through each attribute in the User table when creating an ArchivedUser with self?

```
def archive!
    if ArchivedUser.create(
        user_id: self.id,
        company_id: self.company_id,
        first_name: self.first_name,
        last_name: self.last_name,
        email: self.email,
        encrypted_password: self.encrypted_password,
        password_salt: self.password_salt,
        session_token: self.session_token,
        perishable_token: self.perishable_token,
        role: self.role,
        score: self.score,
        created_at: self.created_at,
        updated_at: self.updated_at,
        api_key: self.api_key,
        device_id: self.device_id,
        time_zone: self.time_zone,
        device_type: self.device_type,
        verified_at: self.verified_at,
        verification_key: self.verification_key,
        uninstalled: self.uninstalled,
        device_details: self.device_details,
        is_archived: self.is_archived,
        registered_at: self.registered_at,
        logged_in_at: self.logged_in_at,
        state: self.state,
        creation_state: self.creation_state,
        language_id: self.language_id,
        offer_count: self.offer_count,
        expired_device_id: self.expired_device_id,
        unique_id: self.unique_id,
        best_language_code: self.best_language_code,
        offer_id: self.offer_id,
        vetted_state: self.vetted_state,
        photo_path: self.photo_path
      )

      self.is_archived = true

      self.email = "#{self.email}.archived#{Time.now.to_i}"
      self.encrypted_password = nil
      self.password_salt      = nil
      self.session_token      = nil
      self.perishable_token   = nil
      self.device_id          = nil
      self.verification_key   = nil
      self.save!

      self.update_column(:api_key, nil)
      UserGroup.delete_all(:user_id => self.id)
    else
      # handle the ArchivedUser not being created properly
    end
  end
```

Thanks for viewing :)

Update:

We were able to figure out the reasons why `ArchivedUser.create(self.attributes.slice!(ArchivedUser.attribute_names)` wasn't working. The first reason is the `create` method requires "bang" to write the object. The second reason was that ArchivedUser has a user_id field, that User doesn't receive until after create. We have to set the user_id: manually with `merge(user_id: self.id)`

The final output looks like 
`ArchivedUser.create!(self.attributes.slice!(ArchivedUser.attribute_names).merge(user_id: self.id))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were on the right track with the first implementation. You just have to use self instead of user.

```
ArchivedUser.create(self.attributes.slice(ArchivedUser.attribute_names))
```

Comment: Thanks Ehren...while this works and shows the flash message, the ArchivedUser isn't actually created in the ArchivedUser table which is odd.

Comment: @VegaStudios Ok, that's probably because of validation. Try using `create!` instead of `create` to get an exception with the validation messages.

Comment: Hmph, that threw an error of Validation failed: User can't be blank. I'm going to have to do some digging...

Comment: Yep! Ah, your ArchivedUser probably has a user field, which the regular user wouldn't have. You just need another line to set that after the slice line. Just `archived_user = ArchivedUser.new(<snip>); archived_user.user = self; archived_user.save!`

Comment: Ah! I'm cumulatively learning :D Thanks for walking me through that.

Comment: Unfortunately, setting the user field that way returned a syntax error, moreover, it returned an error for <snip>. I managed to set the user field with merge, `ArchivedUser.create!(self.attributes.slice (ArchivedUser.attribute_names).merge(user_id: self.id))`

Comment: Ah yes, by <snip> I meant "the other code from before", I just didn't want to type it all in the comment. The real line would be `ArchivedUser.new(self.attributes.slice(ArchivedUser.attribute_names)) ; archived_user.user = self; archived_user.save! `

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/138861/discussion-between-vegastudios-and-ehren-murdick).

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to have a copy of the user that is being archived, I think an elegant way would be to do

`archived_user = user_to_be_archived.dup`

or you can take a look at the amoeba gem, this will do all the heavy lifting including associations if you want.
https://github.com/amoeba-rb/amoeba